# WPF and MVVM tips

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and MVVM pattern. I've been reading about it and I come to a little doubt.

I'll build an WPF application that mainly does access to a database (oracle), but this access is done by an WebService (DataService). My question is in the Model part.

Should I create a class to each table on the database, on my Model, or should I just use the entities that the service provides me?

My guess is use the entities of the service, and then just do the CRUD operations in my application. But I want your opinion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always a good practice to use your own Models. That way, if the Service changes the structure, you will only need to change one point (where you map the item to your own entity), else you would have to change your whole application

Comment: ok then. that helped a lot!

Comment: Then again, a _canonical data model_ has alot going for  it. Otherwise if your service does change you have to remember to update the conversion code between the db/service to the rest of the app.  Pros and cons.

Comment: You're welcome Andre Roque. Accepting the answer would help if you feel it helped. Thanks!